# what is a valid value for REDIRECT URIS in Google Developer Console?

Tags: uri, google-drive-api, google-oauth

By the search results, I have concluded that it is so simple thing that no one has ever encountered such error. But here I am trying for the last hour. The problem is whatever I put in the "**REDIRECT URIS**" box in the Google Developer Console, It says "**Invalid redirect URI**.".. I have tried full URL, URL with and without www, just the domain name, name with relative path and every other possible thing. But response never changes. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you give URI like this 155.155.10.100:2000 while creating Google API, then you can do one thing... go to http://aruljohn.com/ip2hostname.html site enter the above IP address and u will get the hostname for it and then you could enter that in your redact URI space when creating an API.